# How to make text justified in visualforce page

Tags: css, visualforce

I have added an output text in a visualforce page. However, it is left aligned but not justified on right side. How to make it justified as in word documents?

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="row col-md-3 col-md-offset-4 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
<apex:outputText style="font-size:8pt;font-weight:bold;width:30;color:blue;" value="Some text"></apex:outputText>           
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: not getting your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why doesn't

```
 text-align: right;
```

or

```
 text-align: justify;
```

not work?

Comment: text-justify worked. Thank you, I was trying with text-right/left.